# How to run a matlab function remotely fron Fortran code

Tags: matlab, fortran

I've a long (about 1000 lines) and complicated Matlab function (say mat_test.m), which works perfectly fine. On the other hand, I've a complicated set of Fortran codes. I am trying to insert my Matlab function in one of the Fortran code. I don't have much competency in Fortran, so I don't want to rewrite the whole Matlab function in Fortran. Is there a way to define variables in Fortran and remotely call this Matlab function and use the output generated by it?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to call a matlab function from within fortran code. Matlab includes a verbose example of how to properly implement this within the  matlabroot/extern/examples/eng_mat folder, in the `fengdemo.F` file.

[Here is the file showing how it's done.](https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2010a/matlab/r2010a/extern/examples/eng_mat/fengdemo.F)

[Here is the example output of this file, from the mathworks website.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-fortran-applications.html)

Comment: Edited to be a bit more specific, as well as including the sample file.

Comment: So should I replace mxCopyReal8ToPtr with my Matlab function (mat_test.m) and other variables accordingly or is there a different way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

you can execute, or better launch a program in Fortran using

```
call SYSTEM("script.m")
```

now, you edit your Matlab script in a such way to save data in a .txt file;
then you can code in Fortran to read that file;

my idea looks like this:

```
! ...do something in Fortran
call SYSTEM("modified_script.m")
! read data.txt
! continue your works with data from Matlab...
```

PS: you do not need to include any library